# FILE I/O showing Compile Error in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to write a character to a file in C, but this code:

```
case 4: //If the user types 4 (reset)
FILE * fp;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("settings.txt", "w");
fprintf(fp, "a");
int fclose(FILE * fp);

break;
```

shows this error:

```
fileio.c:72:5: error: expected expression
                            FILE * fp;
```

(Yes, I know I used `file * fp` two times, but without both, it shows even more errors.)

How can I fix this?

Comment: @ifconfig They're equivalent, as is `TYPE* NAME`

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. Compiler errors are printed, or shown, not thrown.

Comment: Note that the line containing `int fclose(FILE *fp);` is a declaration of the `fclose()` function — fortunately, it matches what is declared in `<stdio.h>`.  In C99, you can declare one copy of `FILE *fp;` where you do, but you probably shouldn't.  The scope rules are arcane and you're treading on thin ice.  You should probably use a `{` to start a compound statement immediately after the case label, and have a `}` either just before (my preference) or just after (also valid) the `break;`.  You should replace the declaration of `fclose()` with a call — `fclose(fp);`.

Comment: *Without both it shows more errors* - this is because the program wasn't **as wrong** when you didn't repeat the declaration of `fp`, and the compiler could actually continue to make *some sense of it*.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few issues going on here. You can't declare new variables in a case statement. Declare your `fp` outside the switch. Also, only declare it once, and when you close it, call the function instead of writing a new function prototype:

```
fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this code.  The main one you are facing is that you cannot declare variables directly under a case statement.  If you need to declare variables there, you must enclose the code block in curlies, thus:

```
case 4: //If the user types 4 (reset)
    {
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("settings.txt", "w");
        fprintf(fp, "a");
        fclose(fp);
        break;
     }
```

Note that I also fixed your fclose() call--what you had was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In the `close` statement you define a new pointer again. Try just

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("settings.txt", "w");
fprintf(fp, "a");
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Not quite accurate: it doesn't define a new pointer, it defines a function prototype.